# I don't know how to continue this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

my name is Agapita and I have a question about this limit:

> $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac 12}-n^{\frac 34}$

What I have done so far is:

> $n^{\frac 12 - \frac 34}=n^{-\frac 14}=0$

But the solutions say that this limit tends to $-\infty$, so...What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much for your help,
If you don't understand something, please let me know, I'll try to be clearer

Comment: Remember that $n^{a}-n^{b}\neq n^{a-b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would write $$n^{3/4}(n^{-1/4}-1)=n^{3/4}\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}-1\right)$$ and this tends to $-\infty$

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't subtract exponents when the base is same. In particular $n^{\frac 12} - n^{\frac 34} \not = n^{- \frac 14}$

Nevertheless to solve the limit do this:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac 12}-n^{\frac 34} = \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac 12}(1 - n^{\frac 14})$$

Now note that the first factor goes to $\infty$, while the second one to $-\infty$, so their product is $-\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$g(n)=n^{\frac 12}-n^{\frac 34}=f(n^{\frac 14})\quad$ where $f(x)=x^2-x^3$

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac 14}\to+\infty$ we have also $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(n)=-\infty$